# Библиотеки для PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Мне надо писать диплом на PHP. Посоветуйте какие-нибудь отдельные библиотеки (не CMS и не Framework), упрощающие генерацию запросов к БД MySql (лучше отражение класса в строку таблицы базы данных), что-нибудь для модульного тестирования и для упрощённой генерации html-форм и таблиц. Ещё бы пригодился компонент на js/php WYSIWYG-редактор для новостей сайта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По работе с MySQL: проектирование базы, создание запросов и т.д., можно попробовать [SQL Manager for MySQL](http://www.sqlmanager.net/ru/products/mysql/manager) (правда она платная, но все же). На счет WYSIWYG-редактора - наши земляки создают таковой на jQuery [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо за ссылку. В закладки.

Comment: Для подобных целей предпочитаю MySQL Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), но это немного не то, о чём я спрашивал. Redactor- мощная тема! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[PDO](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [Редактор CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

[Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html)  с книгой [PHP, MySQL и Dreamweaver. Разработка интерактивных Web-сайтов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3536208/). В свое время именно эта связка помогла мне написать сайт на диплом и определила мою будущую профессию :)

Comment: Dreamweaver не предлагать. html пишу вручную. Книг по php прочитал достаточно.